# Using RSpec to test SuckerPunch::Job

Tags: rspec, sucker-punch

I've defined the following SuckerPunch Job:

```
class MyWorker
  include SuckerPunch::Job

  def perform(account)
    @account = account
  end

  def params
    @account
  end
end
```

And I want to test it using RSpec:

```
describe MyWorker do
  before { subject.perform("test@mail.nl") }

  its(:params) { should eq "test@mail.nl" }
end
```

This works fine when testing without `include SuckerPunch::Job`. Probably because the subject refers to an instance of `ActorProxy` instead of `MyWorker`.

How should I test `MyWorker`? Or how should I get access to the instance of `MyWorker`? I've read the [Gotchas](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/wiki/Gotchas#wiki-rspec-magic) described in the Celluloid wiki, but the `#wrapped_object` method doesn't to exist (anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch/blob/master/lib/sucker_punch/job.rb, you'll see that `MyWorker.new` is indeed getting redefined to return something other than an instance of the `MyWorker` class. It's actually a `Celluloid::PoolManager`.

Anyway, if you want to access the `params` instance method defined within `MyWorker`, you can `allocate` an instance of the class, as follows:

```
describe MyWorker do
  subject { MyWorker.allocate }
  before { subject.perform("test@mail.nl") }

  its(:params) { should eq "test@mail.nl" }
end
```

`allocate` is an instance method of `Class` is like `new`, but without the call to `initialize`.

Comment: Great thanks! Also the link to the `job.rb` was very instructive.